# Unable to click an item in a list using selenium.webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to further filter the search results by location. I only want the results for "United States", so want to click "United States", whose order changes depending on the keywords.
The following code does not work. No error message, but nothing happens. Thank you!

```
  browser.implicitly_wait(30)
  element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'United 
  States')]")

  browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

[image]

If successful, "United States" should also appear in the Narrow By list:

[image]

```
The HTML source is as follows:

    <ul class="supplemental filters  " aria-labelledby="podfiltersbuttonlocation" data-id="location">
                <li class="preferred">
                    <h3 class="closable">
                        <span>
                            Select location by publications to display at the top of this list. <a 
    href="#" data-action="editpreferred">Edit Settings</a>
                        </span>
                        <button data-action="dismisspreferred" type="button" class="icon la- 
   CloseRemove">
                            <span role="tooltip" class="tooltip">Dismiss this message</span>
                        </button>
                    </h3>
                </li><li>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-id="pf0" data-value="International" id="_sp79k_pf0" 
    data-filtertype="location">
                    <label for="_sp79k_pf0" aria-label="">
                            <span>International</span>
                            <span class="count">83,428</span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-id="pf1" data-value="United States" id="_sp79k_pf1" 
    data-filtertype="location">
                    <label for="_sp79k_pf1" aria-label="">
                            <span>United States</span>
                            <span class="count">31,153</span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-id="pf2" data-value="Non-jurisdictional" id="_sp79k_pf2" 
    data-filtertype="location">
                    <label for="_sp79k_pf2" aria-label="">
                            <span>Non-jurisdictional</span>
                            <span class="count">10,936</span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-id="pf3" data-value="California" id="_sp79k_pf3" data- 
    filtertype="location">
                    <label for="_sp79k_pf3" aria-label="">
                            <span>California</span>
                            <span class="count">6,785</span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-id="pf4" data-value="Georgia" id="_sp79k_pf4" data- 
   filtertype="location">
                    <label for="_sp79k_pf4" aria-label="">
                            <span>Georgia</span>
                            <span class="count">2,814</span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li class="more">
                    <button data-action="moreless" class="icon la-ShowMore" type="button">
                        More
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li class="sel-multi">
                    <button type="button" data-action="selmulti" rel="modal" href="/modals/select- 
   Filters.shtml">Select multiple</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: To click on the element you need to use element.click()

Comment: ..and I think you'd want to click on the checkbox instead of the span tag so something like: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@data-value,'United States')]".click();  (Also consider using a webdriverwait to wait for it to be clickable if necessary...)

Comment: You're right: After changed to this, it works: element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@data-value,'United States')]")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Comment: @VictorWang Did you edit your post to correct the code? The code in the comment you just made is the same as the one in the main post.

Comment: Slightly different. I was clicking the span. As pcalkins pointed out, I should have clicked the checkbox, which works.

Answer (score 0):

To click on `checkbox` induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `Xpath`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='supplemental filters  ']//li[.//span[text()='United States']]/input[@type='checkbox']"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```